# How can I delete all the tweets in my timeline

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am using this [script](https://gist.github.com/davej/113241) to delete all the tweets in my timeline, but unforutnately, the very old tweets and retweets couldn't be undone. Is there any trick to delete the very old (between 2009-2011) ?

```
tweets= api.user_timeline(id=user.id, include_rts=True)

for tweet in tweets :
     api.DestroyStatus(tweet.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things:

1. [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) will give you up to the most recent 3,200 tweets. Anything more than that won't be returned. So it comes down to how many tweets were after 2009-2011 period.
2. Tweepy does not have `api.DestroyStatus` it's `destroy_status`. Just making sure, it's right in the script you provided but just to prevent any confusion.

It's a possibility that if you delete those 3,200 all you have to do is rerun the script to get the later ones. This is assuming that after the initial deletion the 3,201-6,400 get moved up. It's something you can try by repeating the bulk delete script you got.

Give it a period to clear with Twitter to prevent any issues. Sometimes that can take days unfortunately. Even though the tweet is deleted from view it doesn't mean it's deleted from the servers.

**Edit**

Came across this earlier and wasn't sure if a [fresh start](https://support.twitter.com/articles/18906#freshstart) is what you might be looking into. Twitter has a procedure you can follow for that worth looking into.